# Nested IF, AND, OR, VLOOKUP Statement Excel 2016

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested, vlookup

I need a formula that performs the following: (1) If the value in Raw$G=A5, AND (2) If the value of Raw$J = ng/L OR mg/L OR ug/L, then return the value "mg/L", otherwise return the value in column J. I've copied my two attempts at this, below (one uses a Vlookup, the other just refers to column J directly). Both return the value in J regardless, as though the first half of my equation isn't being interpreted correctly. Any thoughts on what I'm missing, are appreciated!

```
=IF(OR(Raw!$J:$J="ng/L",Raw!$J:$J="ug/L",Raw!$J:$J="mg/L"),IF(Raw!$G:$G=$A6,"mg/L",Raw!$J:$J))


=IF(OR(Raw!$J:$J="ng/L",Raw!$J:$J="ug/L",Raw!$J:$J="mg/L"),IF(Raw!$G:$G=$A5,"mg/L",VLOOKUP($A5,Raw!$G:$J,4,FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
=If(OR(INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="ng/L",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="mg/L",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="ug/L"),"mg/l",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0)))
```

It should do what you want.  It will cause an error if the value in A5 is not found in Raw!G:G.  If you want to deal with that error then wrap it in an IFERROR():

```
=IFERROR(If(OR(INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="ng/L",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="mg/L",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))="ug/L"),"mg/l",INDEX(Raw!J:J,MATCH(A5,Raw!G:G,0))),A5 & " Not Found")
```

Comment: That worked beautifully- thanks. How do you know when to use the INDEX/MATCH combination instead of Vlookup?

Comment: You could have used the VLookup in this case.  Vlookup only works if the data you are searching is to the left of the data you are returning.   In this case I Index/Match was the first to pop into my head.  The Vlookup would have been `VLOOKUP(A5,Raw!G:J,4,FALSE)`  It should work in place of the INDEX/MATCH. @KRD

Comment: Good on you for using INDEX/MATCH, rather than VLOOKUP. INDEX/MATCH is faster and more adaptable than VLOOKUP in every case. The only reason to use VLOOKUP over INDEX/MATCH is because VLOOKUP appears simpler for beginners to use. However, once you get your head around how INDEX/MATCH works, it is easier as you don't need to count columns or worry about columns being inserted in the future.